# How do I get a line to wrap around textview without passing through the text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview, android-relativelayout

I am planning to achieve something like this:

```
---------------Text---------------
```

where "-----" is actually a line ,(view line perhaps? or a divider) .

more accurately, this is an example of what i am trying to achieve:
[image]
I was wondering how do I achieve that in my textview. here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mydate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a single, full-width line, and then putting the TextView on top of it. If you give the TextView the same background color as the parent's background, and give the TextView some left and right padding, it will look like you example.

You can use this for the line (line.xml in your res/drawable directory) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line"
>
    <stroke
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:width="1dp"
    />
</shape>
```

and then use this layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mydate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: the line goes thru the text. i was looking to wrap it around the text  without striking thru it

Comment: my bad, was missing background, works perfectly, thanks!